# 'System.Data.Common.DbDataReader.IsDBNull(int)' has some invalid arguments

Tags: c#, sql, sqldatareader

I'm trying to handle null values coming from a database column (which has either `int` or `null`)

I wrote this code :

```
int? nullInt = null; 
int? typeTwo = myReader.IsDBNull(myReader["Type2"]) ? nullInt : (int)myReader["Type2"];
```

But I get this error :

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Data.Common.DbDataReader.IsDBNull(int)' has some invalid
>   arguments
>   Can you tell me how to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `IsDBNull` accepts `ìnt` as a parameter. You can get the number of your `Type2` column with [`GetOrdinal` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatarecord.getordinal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like;

```
myReader.IsDBNull(myReader.GetOrdinal("Type2"))
```